# Python:Printing rows only if a part of the row meets conditions

Tags: python, python-2.7

Apologies if this is a very basic question. I'm new to python and am attempting to get python to read a .txt file and print lines only if conditions are met. Below is a (very tiny) sample of my data:

[image]

I have done this before for one condition and it worked using the code:

```
file=open("sample.txt")

for row in file:
    if not "1e-22" in row:
        continue
    else:
        print row
```

However, I also need to also filter out the data based on columns 3 and 4 and I have tried multiple ways to do this with a variety of syntax errors. I've tried a multiude of different ways to no avail. My most recent attempt is below:

```
file=open("sample.txt")
for row in file:
    if file[4] is not "80":
        continue
    else:
        print row
```

This brings up the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 3, in <module>
    if file[0:4] is not "80":
TypeError: 'file' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I've also tried converting the input into int, which would be earier to work with and I get the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 3, in <module>
    file=int(file)

    TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'file'
```

I've tried so many different ways I think I'm missing something fundamental and would be very grateful for your help.

Comment: this is CSV. better use CSV module instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried if file[row,4] is not "80" as suggested @DavidG and I got the following error File "test1.py", line 3, in <module>
    if file[row,4] is not "80":
TypeError: 'file' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: @DavidG No I'm afraid it didn't. There was no error, but the program outputted nothing.

Answer (score 0):

try following:

```
file=open("sample.txt")
for row in file:
    if row[4] is not "80":
        continue
    else:
        print row
```

It should be row and not file

Comment: Hi @Bhavesh Ghodasara, no errors were returned, but the program did not output anything.

Comment: @DavidG. The code worked previously to remove any rows with e-values that didn't match so I assume so? Is it possible python is not reading my data as a table? I told python to print row[4] and it outputted the following values:
4
4
4
4
4
4

Comment: Apolgies, it actually outputted 5
4
4
4
4
4
4